# REST Controller test: MockMvc.andExpect doesn't work with ENUM

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-test, mockmvc

I am using @WebMvcTest and MockMvc mockMvc;

I am trying to do:

```
  mockMvc.perform(get("/api/v2/developers/12"))
                    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.sportType").value("FOOTBAL"))
```

But i get:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: JSON path "$.sportType" 
Expected :FOOTBALL
Actual   :FOOTBALL
```

FOOTBAL - is enum value, i also tryied to use instead "FOOTBAL":

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.sportType").value(SportType.FOOTBALL))
//OR
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.sportType").value(String.valueOf(SportType.FOOTBALL)))
//OR
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.sportType").value(Arrays.asList(SportType.FOOTBALL)))
```

How looks my JSON :

```
{
    "name": "JOHN",
    "sportType": "FOOTBALL"
}
```

Comment: i will recommend to use string `.andExpect(jsonPath("$.sportType").value("FOOTBALL"))`

Comment: @Deadpool thanks for recommendation, but how i said above, is does not work )

Comment: You are right, works, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the response is JSON string and `sportType` is string type i will recommend to compare it as string instead of enum

```
andExpect(jsonPath("$.sportType").value("FOOTBALL"))
```

Or you can also use [Matchers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/result/MockMvcResultMatchers.html#jsonPath-java.lang.String-org.hamcrest.Matcher-)

```
andExpect(jsonPath("$.sportType", is("FOOTBALL")))
```

Answer (score 3):

@Deadpool answer is correct.
But instead to compare with string i would suggest to use the .name() / .toString() method from ur enum.

```
anExpect(jsonPath("$.sportType"), is(SportType.FOOTBALL.name()))
```